# pyaudio can't be installed

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio using pip command `pip3 install PyAudio`
but I got this error

```
 Failed building wheel for pyaudio
```

and also

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6wyv5apg/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mfb7gpm9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6wyv5apg/pyaudio/
```

then I tried to install using wheel file

using this command `pip3 install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

but I got this error

```
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

how can I solve it ?

I am using python 3.6.9